# Use of the subjunctive

Tags: subjunctive

Here is an edited quotation from Ulrich Chaussy's *Das Oktoberfest-Attentat*:

> Verfolgt man die Herkunft der Mixtur weiter, entpuppt sich der Rufmord an Lewin als ein Spiel zwischen Nürnberg, Tel Aviv, Paris, das - ***man staune*** - am Ende wieder am Startpunkt anlangt.

Why does the author use the subjunctive in the interjection?  Could he just say "man staunt"? What would be the difference in meaning.  Is this very subtle use of language or just an academic quirk?

Comment: Welcome to German SE! I edited your post because there's no book titled *Das Oktoberfest Attentat* (as it was cited in the question originally). That phrase features a [*Deppenleerzeichen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita) (fool's blank) and would be incorrect from an orthographical point of view. The title changed from *Oktoberfest. Ein Attentat* (1st ed.) over *Oktoberfest. Das Attentat* (2nd ed.) to *Das Oktoberfest-Attentat und der Doppelmord von Erlangen*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Man staunt (Indikativ)

means that the author is informing the reader that people (or he himself) are astonished, while

> man staune (Konjunktiv I)

is an invitation or request to the reader to be astonished or to marvel.

A similar, quite popular, use of Konjunktiv as a request is:

> Man möge mir die Frage verzeihen ...

or

> Man verzeihe mir die Frage ...

A classic blessing from the Old Testament introduced by Martin Luther to protestant liturgy also is a nice example, adressing an appeal to god. The form used today is:

> Der Herr segne und behüte dich, er lasse sein Angesicht leuchten über dir und sei dir gnädig. Der Herr hebe sein Angesicht über dich und gebe dir Frieden.

Note how this is addressed to the person being blessed (dich/dir), but wishes that a third person, god, would do something.

Comment: Is "man staune" equivalent with "man soll gestaunt sein"?

Comment: That doesn't work for two reasons: _staunen_ is intransitive, so a passive of it is unacceptable; and the passive inverts the meaning (_man soll verziehen sein_ = "one has to be forgiven"). The closest would be _man soll staunen_, but that's rather unidiomatic in this position. It has a completely differnent ring than the Konjunktiv.

Comment: @NicholasMcAulay You meant *erstaunt* instead of _gestaunt_, right? *Man soll erstaunt sein* is a grammatical sentence, but it's more like a third-party summary of someone saying *man staune*, while *man staune* is the prompt itself. Example conversation: A: "Man staune." -- B (to C): "What did A say?" -- C (to B): "*Man soll erstaunt sein*, according to A." *Man staune* is also replacable by *man **sei er**staunt*.

Answer (score 3):

That's no subjunctive, but rather an archaic remnant of an *imperative* in 3rd person. (This mode is actually called "[Jussiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv)")

This was used roughly in the middle ages by upper-class persons to express contemptousness to the adressed person.

The King would have addressed the servant with

> Er schenke mir noch Wein nach

Comment: I understand that this is a matter of perspective, but I would rather say that we use Konjunktiv as a substitute for an imperative for persons other than the second. And we still do that, I'd argue, when we use third person plural as a polite address.

Comment: @CarstenS Yep, clearly a matter of perspective - I think, however, it's easier to understand for a non-native speaker to consider it a sort of imperative instead of Konjunktiv, which is usualy assumed to have entirely different purposes. Agree, however, that the verb form is aligned with the Konjunktiv.

Comment: Es handelt sich um einen Konjunktiv I. Das Deutsche kennt keine eigene Verbform "Jussiv".

Comment: @DavidVogt Ja, es ist ein Konjunktiv. Aber kein Subjunktiv (was gefragt war).

Comment: *(Present) subjunctive* ist der englische Ausdruck für *Konjunktiv I*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Nein. Das ist nur etwas ähnliches.

Comment: This still exists (as an archaic form) in English too: "long live the king", "so be it", "hallowed be your name, your kingdom come, your will be done" and so on.

Comment: Dann weiß ich nicht, was Konjunktiv I auf Englisch heißt. In der Antwort wird die Form jedenfalls weiterhin fälschlicherweise als Imperativ bezeichnet.

Comment: @tofro, I fully agree that the form functions as an imperative here, and that that was important to point out.

Comment: @tofro Regarding the question whether subjunctive is the English term for the German *Konjunktiv* or only something similar: please note that here on German SE we also excusively use the tag *subjunctive* for questions about *Konjunktiv I* and *II*. To the best of my knowledge, it's a rather undisputed translation in the linguistical field.

Comment: @DavidVogt Der deutsche Konjunktiv I heißt Konjunktiv I auf Englisch. Der englische subjunctive ist nicht exakt dasselbe (logischerweise) und der französische subjunctif schon gar nicht. Es ist nicht immer sinnvoll, diese Begrifflichkeiten gleichzusetzen.

Comment: Für die Nichtgleichsetzung genügt das Bewußtsein, daß man über verschiedene Sprachen spricht. Ich glaube nicht, daß diejenigen Grammatiken, die z.B. das deutsche Präteritum als *simple past* bezeichnen, davon ausgehen, daß es in jeder Hinsicht mit dem englischen *simple past* identisch sei. Im übrigen ist die Behauptung "der deutsche Konjunktiv I heißt Konjunktiv I auf Englisch" empirisch falsch: Ich habe Grammatiken im Regal stehen, die *present subjunctive* schreiben. Das mag dir nicht gefallen, ist aber so.

Comment: @tofro I think *that's no subjunctive* would be too short-sighted because the form obviously *is* subjunctive (or *Konjunktiv I*, whatever one prefers). However, it is also a very important point (especially for language learners) that the pattern of using subjunctive as imperative replacement is partly productive at most nowadays. So maybe the conclusion could be that the form morphologically represents subjunctive I, but subjunctive I is used in an archaic way to express an order (jussive). In Latin, that kind of subjunctive usage is called *coniunctivus iussivus*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus That's what the answer tries to convey - fully agree.